# make alias for method nested deep in object

Tags: javascript

I have some objects that have lots of nested layers of properties and methods that are unfortunately also not very descriptive of what they actually do. Would it be possible to at the beginning of my function that sets them to a shorter more descriptive variable name?

This isn't working, but it seems like I should be able to do something similar.

```
var out = {
    mid1: true,
    middle: {
        inner: function (value) {
            return value * 2;

        }

    }
};

console.log(out.middle.inner(5)); //10

var i = function(value){ out.middle.inner(value);} 

console.log(i(6)); //undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you forgot a `return` in your `i` function.

```
var i = function(value){ return out.middle.inner(value);}
```